# systemd: How to unmask a service whose unit file is empty?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, network-interface

I tried to start `wpa_supplicant.service`, but I got the following error:

> Failed to start wpa_supplicant.service: Unit wpa_supplicant.service is masked.

I tried unmasking it using `systemctl unmask wpa_supplicant.service`, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```
systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service
```

returns

> Loaded: masked (/usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicaant.service; masked; vendor preset: disabled) Active: inactive (dead)

What seems really strange is that when I check the `wpa_supplicant.service` file it's an empty document.
How can I unmask the service?

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux my problem is i want to start a netctl profile and wpa_supplicant is needed to bring the interface up but since it's masked i get an error ... is there any other ways to start wpa_supplicant?

Comment: I also tried using NetworkManager but it also depends on wpa_supplicant

Comment: See *exactly* what is masked: `systemctl list-unit-files --state=masked`

Comment: wpa_supplicant-nl80211@.service                                                        
wpa_supplicant-wired@.service                                                                
wpa_supplicant.service                                                                             
wpa_supplicant@.service

Comment: when i try to unmask any other service besides `wpa_supplicant.service` i get the following error: `Failed to get properties: Unit name *.service is missing the instance name.`

Comment: What seems really strange is that when i check the wpa_supplicant.service file it's an empty document

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A service unit that is empty (0 bytes) will be parsed by `systemd` as masked. While `systemctl mask <unit>` works by symlinking the service to `/dev/null`, systemd appears to just check if a file is 0 bytes when read to determine if a unit is masked. This results in the misleading message about a masked service.
You need to figure out why the service unit is empty.

As to how to unmask a service whose unit file is empty... You "unmask" the service by making the unit non-empty, which is going to be dependent on *why* the unit is empty.

Comment: just curious about the check. is masked service is zero-length or it must be linked to /dev/null. can't find spec about it.

Answer (score 13):

8 comments and no answer - really guys, focus on the question. How to unmask a systemd service!!!!
You can try `systemctl unmask your_app.service` , but if your service link has been symlinked to `/dev/null`, this will fail. The following is the recommended process:

1. Check that the unit file is a symlink to `/dev/null`:

   ```
   file /lib/systemd/system/your_app.service
   OR
   file /etc/systemd/system/your_app.service
   ```

   It should return:

   ```
   /lib/systemd/system/your_app.service: symbolic link to /dev/null
   ```
2. Delete the symlink:

   ```
   sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/your_app.service
   ```
3. Reload systemd daemon as you changed a service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
4. Check the status:

   ```
   systemctl status your_app
   ```

Happy Hosting :)

Comment: If you bothered reading those comments instead of "focusing (exclusively) on the question" you'd know that your answer doesn't apply here...

Comment: I'm not sure if "deleting a file/symlink" created during package installation is really a viable solution. At least - after reinstalling the `pulseaudio`-package (to get this symlink to `/dev/null` back), everything worked as expected :-)